Dhanvantri and Lakshmi pooja huge Benifits?
Doing a dhanavantri pooja with tablets and saying we invented is comforting like vitamins. What are detailed poojas? Lakshmi pooja round robin coin counting and 5-6 stotra mala is good? Can you also read devi poojas to Lakshmi for wealth? What is stastical experience of amplification of wealth per frequency of pooja? Mine is happy.
